# Return UTF-16 encoded gzip content response to browser

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http, browser

I have a number of files that are saved to disc and compressed using gzip as they in the end are going to be displayed in a browser. I use ASP.NET MVC and by adding the below header in code

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
```

i get the following response header

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:791
Content-Type:text/xml
```

This works ***almost*** fine. The files are XML files with the UTF-16 XML declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

To get that to display correctly in IE I need to also encode the response as UTF-16. *What do I need to change in the response* to get this to work without breaking the gzip decompressing and so on?

**Update #1**

Also tried adding charset header to return the below response headers

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:791
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=UTF-16
```

This however breaks the gzip compression and the result is uncompressed gzip content ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the scenario you're describing. I see nothing wrong with your approach which leads me to believe that the problem lies somewhere else. Please follow the same steps that I took in order to verify that nothing else in your code is broken and then we can continue the debug.

I produced an UTF-16 encoded xml file using Visual Studio and then gzipped it to disk using Total Commander.

The quick-and-dirty way of sending the required response would be something like this (in your mvc controller)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/test.xml.gz");
    var result = new FilePathResult(path, "text/xml");

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    Response.Charset = "utf-16";

    return result;
}
```

Now, while this will work it's not the idiomatic way to do it in MVC and it's a bit frowned upon. The proper way would be to implement your own action result and let the result set the appropriate headers when it's executing. Using this approach post-processing of your result can occur with a "clean" http context.

So, here's an example of such an action result.

```
public class BinaryFileResult : FilePathResult
{
    public string Charset { get; set; }
    public string ContentEncoding { get; set; }

    public BinaryFileResult(string fileName, string contentType) : base(fileName, contentType) { }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        if (this.Charset != null)
            response.Charset = this.Charset;

        if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", this.ContentEncoding);

        base.WriteFile(response);
    }
}
```

With this is our toolbelt we may reduce the action method down to something like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return new BinaryFileResult(Server.MapPath("~/Content/test.xml.gz"), "text/xml")
    {
        Charset = "utf-16",
        ContentEncoding = "gzip"
    };
}
```

Using both of these methods I'm able to look at the properly decoded xml file in IE9. Have a go and let me know how if it works.

**Update**
Here's the files I used to test it out. As I said, they produce the appropriate result on IE9 on my machine.

- http://freakcode.s3.amazonaws.com/so/10090975/test.xml
- http://freakcode.s3.amazonaws.com/so/10090975/test.xml.gz

Comment: The problem was me using "new StreamWriter(gz)" instead of "new StreamWriter(gz, Encoding.Unicode)" when writing the file ... Your answer however helped me solving the issue so I'll accept it.